# Used dd command on Time Machine disk

Tags: time-machine, partition

I was trying to write an img file to an SD Card and just assumed it was the same disk as a minute ago but it wasn't. I have dd'd a Raspbian image onto my Time Machine disk and need a way to restore it. I'm trying Disk Drill Free to restore the disk but I am not sure if it is going to work.

This is the command I used:

```
dd if=/../image.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

The size of the image was 1.5gb.

Solutions / tips please!

Comment: Depends on how long `dd` ran before you noticed.  If you have zapped the disk's first few hundred blocks completely, I would not have any high hopes for being able to recover.

Comment: @tripleee dd finished by the time I noticed

Comment: @klanomath tm only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dd like this overwrites the partition table and major file system related areas of your main volume - assuming the disk was partitioned with one major volume dedicated to Time Machine.

The common partition table of an external disk looks like this:

Example 1 (8 TB disk, physical block size 512 Bytes):

```
sudo gpt -r show disk1
        start         size  index  contents
            0            1         PMBR
            1            1         Pri GPT header
            2           32         Pri GPT table
           34            6         
           40       409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  15627380656      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  15627790296       262151         
  15628052447           32         Sec GPT table
  15628052479            1         Sec GPT header
```

Dd'ing 1.5 GB to this disk will overwrite the primary GUID partition table, the 200 MiB EFI partition (index 1) and about 1.3 GB (or ~2.5 million blocks) of the major volume (index 2).

Example 2 (6 TB disk, physical block size 4096 Bytes):

```
sudo gpt -r show disk2
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2           4         Pri GPT table
           6       76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       76806  1465012725      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1465089531       32768         
  1465122299           4         Sec GPT table
  1465122303           1         Sec GPT header
```

Dd'ing 1.5 GB to this disk will overwrite the primary GUID partition table, the 300 MiB EFI partition (index 1) and about 1.2 GB (or ~293000 blocks) of the major volume (index 2).

Overwriting the first 1.3/1.2 GB of a main volume usually deletes the catalog file, the attributes file, the allocation file and the extents file - all major invisible files located at the beginning of a volume and determining the file system.

Data recovery is only possible then by using a "deep scan" feature of a data recovery tool which searches the whole disk for files or fragment of files and tries to determine the type by specific file headers or other internal structures of the file.

On a backup disk this is probably only worthwhile if the backup contains files deleted from the main disk but still have some relevance for you - but on the other hand: why have they been deleted then...

Depending on the size or type of the disk and the interface (USB/Thunderbolt) a deep scan may take very long (10 MB/s - ~250 MB/s). A deep scan of the example disk1 (8 TB/USB 3) would take at least 40 hours.

---

If you choose to refrain from a data recovery and start the Time Machine backup from scratch, simply open Disk Utility, erase the whole disk and partition it to one disk with a GUID Partition Map and OS X Extended (Journaled) format. Then choose the new empty volume in the Time Machine preferences pane and configure a new TM task.

Comment: Is spotlight keeping some copy of catalogue file? This shows how retarded hfs is :( GPT could be restored from the second header but fs references is another matter... I'm wondering if maybe some parts are kept in spotlight but then I remember that spotlight isn't indexing time machine backups. By overwriting 1.2 gb you can kiss 6tb data goodbye cause of the flawed fs allocation :/ and hfs is crippled anyways with its endians bit fliping

Comment: @PJJ Checking my disks (with iDefrag) parts of the spotlight database would have been deleted also as well as some journal files.

Comment: Well it's good that Apple rolls a new fs q1-2q this year, I'm sure of one new feature: no more bit flips ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wiping the first 1.5 GB of a disk does rather a lot of damage, and data recovery may require a lot of effort. So if it is "just" a backup and you have no urgent need to access any deleted files, it might be easiest to just reformat the disk using Disk Utility and reconnect the disk to Time Machine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Testdisk deep scan will be the first thing I'll try, like the others pointed out this is unfortunate since you shredded the fs catalogue, partition table has a backup header but this is half the problem since it describes only the table and not what's on the volume- that's kept in nodes within the volume, partially seen when listing .dotfiles in fs root / - you can see few.

I don't know that much about hfs+ fs but deep scanning pattern matching might be only option. Thinking about it, such fs would be very bad implementation if hfs can be crippled by wiping 1% of total volume space- so maybe it's not that bad, I doubt Apple will have seething like that as its proprietary file system but- I don't know for sure. Gotta sip through some docs. Don't do anything that might write to this disk yet and wait a bit until more people read this- and deep scanning takes a lot of time, I know that pain :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already reformatted the drive. There wasn't anything I really needed on it.

Comment: Ohh, well if so then it's not that bad - otherwise you would be old before surface block read churns 6tb over tcp/ip ;)

Comment: One question: did you used sudo dd or just dd as command?

Comment: I used sudo dd.

Comment: Ok, was wondering how did you dd'ed the volume without sudo ;) still- you can sudo bash or zsh first (which I do often cause I'm lazy- and bad things happen) but I don't recommend this-